# Is $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n - \bar X_m)$ tight?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

My question is a bit more specific than the title.

Suppose $\{X_i\}$ is iid with finite second moments, and suppose we select some random subset $D_n \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $n_d = |D_n|$, and suppose that $D_n$ is independent of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Moreover, suppose that $n_d/n \xrightarrow{p} c$ for some constant $c \in (0,1)$.

Now, is it true that
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \frac{1}{n_d}\sum_{i \in D_n} X_i\right)= O_p(1)$$

I know that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \frac{1}{n_d}\sum_{i \in D_n} X_i = o_p(1)$, and I basically want to know if $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \frac{1}{n_d}\sum_{i \in D_n} X_i = O_p(n^{-1/2})$

Comment: Interesting format! May I know what domain you're looking at currently?

Comment: We can assume everything is real valued

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clear. By domain, I meant "probability topic"

Comment: Oh I see! this just came up in a working model for inference in experiments conducted under covariate-adaptive randomization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Clarification** I understand your big O notation as probabilistic big O notation.
**Short Answer**
Yes, you have the right speculation.
And, if my calculations are right, your speculation is still valid if $(n_d;n \ge 1)$ is a sequence of random variables such that :

1. $n_d/n$ is bounded below by a real number $a>0$
2. $n_d/n$ converges in law (as a sequence of real random variables)

**Main idea**

We'll prove the result the same way that we've done for the central limit theorem. That is, by characteristic functions and Levy's continuity theorem.

**Long answer**
WLOG: $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=0, \mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$

Let $\phi$ be the characteristic function of $X$, that is:
$$\phi(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}( e^{i\lambda X_1})$$

The finiteness of the second moment of $X$ implies that:
$$\phi(\lambda) = \exp ( \lambda^2(-1+o_{\lambda}(1)))$$
where $|o_{\lambda}(1)| \le h( |\lambda|)$ for some increasing function $h$ bounded around $0$ and $h(\lambda) \xrightarrow{\lambda \rightarrow 0^+} 0$

($o_\lambda$  can be complex but doesn't matter)

Let

- $d^n_i:= 1_{ i \in \mathbb{D_n}}$ 
  When there is no confusion, by abuse of notation, we'll let $d_i= d^n_i$
- $Y_n$ is the random quantity that we want to study, i.e
  $$Y_n:= \sqrt{n}\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right) - \dfrac{1}{n_d}\left(\sum_{k \in D_n} X_k\right) \right)$$
  So clearly, $Y_n$ can be written as
  $$Y_n = \sqrt{n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{d_k}{n_d}\right)X_k\right)$$
  So, by independence between $D_n$ and $(X_i)$, for all $\lambda$ real, we have:
  $$\phi_{Y_n}(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}\left( \prod_{k=1}^n \phi\underbrace{\left( \lambda \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\lambda \sqrt{n}\dfrac{d_k}{n_d} \right)}_{ =o(1/\sqrt{n}) ~\text{regardless of the value of}~ d_i} \right)$$

Thus, by the remark we have to $\phi$, we imply that
$$\phi_{Y_n}(\lambda)  = \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\lambda \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\lambda \sqrt{n}\dfrac{d_k}{n_d} \right)^2(-1+ o(1)) \right] \right)$$

where $|o(1)| \le h\left( \frac{b|\lambda|}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ for every $o(1)$ and some $b$ depending only on $a$.

As $ \left(\lambda \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\lambda \sqrt{n}\dfrac{d_k}{n_d} \right)^2 \ge 0$, we have:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\lambda \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\lambda \sqrt{n}\dfrac{d_i}{n_d} \right)^2(-1+ o(1)) = (-1+o(1))\underbrace{\left[ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\lambda \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\lambda \sqrt{n}\dfrac{d_k}{n_d} \right)^2 \right]}_{ = \lambda^2\left(\dfrac{n}{n_d}-1\right)} $$

Thus
$$ \phi_{Y_n}(\lambda) = \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{ -(1+o(1))\lambda^2( n/n_d-1)} \right] \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow +\infty} e^{-\lambda^2(1/c-1) }$$

Therefore, by Levy's theorem, we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}( Y_n ) \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}( 0, 1/c-1)$$

Hence the conclusion.
$\square$